# Angular routing component push in/out animation

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-animations

I'm trying to animate a component to *"push itself into"* and "*get pushed out of*" view. Currently, a single container element hosts one component which occupies 100% of the space.

The animation will trigger a second component (living within a router-outlet) to push itself in **from the right** and share 50% of the space with the first component (which will need to have a smooth animation for the shrink).

Vise versa, the exit animation will look like the first component is *"pushing"* the second out of view.

Below is the template file for this scenario (assume that the animations have been imported correctly in the component file)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="component-1"
    [@triggerComponent1]="outlet.isActivated ? 'shrink' : 'stretch'">
    <component-1></component-1>
  </div>

  <div class="component-2 col-6"
    [@triggerComponent2]="outlet.isActivated ? 'open' : 'close'">
    <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here are the respective animation trigger functions

```
export const animation1 = trigger('triggerComponent1', [
  state('stretch', style({
    flex: '0 0 auto',
    width: '100%'
  })),
  state('shrink', style({
    flex: '0 0 auto',
    width: '50%'
  })),
  transition('* => stretch', animate('400ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)')
  ),
  transition('* => shrink', animate('400ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'))
]);

export const animation2 = trigger('triggerComponent2', [
  state('open', style({
    transform: 'translateX(0%)'
  })),
  state('close', style({
    transform: 'translateX(100%)'
  })),
  transition('* => open', animate('400ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)')
  ),
  transition('* => close', animate('400ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'))
]);
```

The problem with this approach is that the animations are not happening in parallel. Component 1 will smoothly shrink, exposing white space to its **right**. Then, when the *slide* animation completes, Component 2 just "appears".

Ideally, I need to combine the animations with a `group()` but am not sure how to write the trigger nor how I would include it in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a stack blitz for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/expanding-drawer-animation?file=src/app/animations.ts

here is how I did it.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="component-1">
     <div class="content">
          <button (click)="toggle()">expand</button>
          <h1>{{ isExpanded }}</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="component-2" [@slideIn]="isExpanded ? 'open' : 'close'">
         <div class="content">
         <h1>Bender?! You stole the atom.</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Then some CSS.

```
 .container {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
   background: red;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 }

 .content {
   padding: 10px;
 }

 .component-1 {
   flex: 1;
   background: rgb(161, 161, 255);
 }

 .component-2 {
   flex: 1;
   background: green;
   max-width: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

The parent is a div flex and the 2 children are 50 / 50 by doing flex:1.   Then you can overflow hidden the right div and set the max-width to 50% : 0  based on the variable.  we are going to use that to trigger the animation.

```
  import {
  animate,
  state,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';

export class Animations {
  static page = [
    trigger('slideIn', [
      state('close', style({ maxWidth: '0%', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('open', style({ maxWidth: '50%', visibility: 'visible' })),
      transition('close <=> open', [animate('.6s ease-in-out')]),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 1 }),
        animate('.6s 1.2s ease-in-out'),
      ]),
    ]),
  ];
}
```

hope this helps!

I also did a second one in the stackblitz for you using position absolute and sliding over 50% with padding like I said in my comment below.

Comment: This solution assumes that I am adding route data in the routing module, which is not the case @Zuriel

Comment: Also, in the code I provided in the question, the router outlet already is wrapped in an animation trigger

Comment: ok this is easy.    step 1.   remove the col-6 stuff   basically you want the PARENT div of both components to be display flex and both flex: 1.  THEN you want your CURRENT column to have max-width 0.   the one with col 6 and when you animate it in, all your doing is animating the max-width to 50% and setting the display on etc.      I did a quick codepen with the 2 and capped the parent to 600px so you can see, if you change maxwidth between 0 and 50% you will get the results you need.   (hopefully) 

https://codepen.io/Zuriel/pen/ZEyxmBL

Comment: hey I redid the answer for you in stackblitz using angular and triggers so that you can see what I was saying. Hope this helps! Mark this correct if you can use this! thanks.. also if you do not want the 'contents' to reflow, then you can't use max width, you need to set the parent to position relative, then set the internal drawer to absolute and use translation right 0 : -50% etc where your drawer is sliding in and out but not reflowing in size, the main content would have to have an animation for that as well if you wanted to animate something like padding-right 0 : 50% etc